# Show degree symbol in a TextView

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to show 50 degrees in my activity using `TextView` as shown below

[image]

I really don't know how to do this and by googling  I found this XML code

```
android:text="50&#xb0;"
```

And I have no idea what the above code is.
Can anyone please explain to me what exactly that does and how it works.

Comment: Doesn't `50°` work?!

Comment: The above string is a decimal representation of the unicode degree symbol

Comment: It works for me, if I insert this character **directly**. Without any hex code or other fantasy methods (i.e.: entity name or how is it called). Because **1** - I use the UTF-8 declaration in my xml files. **2** - I save my files with Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&#xb0;` is just the standard way of inserting special characters into XML. You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references for a more full description, but to break it down:

- `&` indicates it's the start of a special character.
- `#` means the character is indicated with a number (versus a special string code, e.g. `&amp;` for ampersands).
- `x` means the numeric code is a hexadecimal value.
- `b0` the hex value for the degree symbol (176 in decimal).
- `;` ends the sequence.

An alternative representation would be `&#176;` which uses the decimal value instead of hex.

Hence, you can insert any special character if you know its ASCII decimal/hex value.

Answer (score 46):

1. For Celsius  ℃ use :

   ```
        "\u2103"
   ```

for Fahrenheit   use:

```
      "\u2109"
```

for only degree symbol without c or f use:

```
     "\u00B0"
```

For example:

```
      String TemperatureMeasurementStr = String.valueOf(measurement.getTemperature()) + "\u2103";
```

Or simple example:

```
      String TemperatureMeasurementStr = "37"+ "\u2103";
```

And set the string in your textView

```
      public TextView temperatureTV;                     
      temperatureTV.setText(TemperatureMeasurementStr);
```

2. if you want just to add the symbol to the xml layout file - just use:

   ```
      android:text="37\u2103"
   ```

for example:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/temperature_measure"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/temperature_icon"
     android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperature_icon"
     android:text="37\u2103"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textSize="50sp"
  />
```

3. if you want this symbol to be smaller or in different color or style then the number  (lets say "normal" while the number itself is "bold") then you can use SpannableString:

Like this:

```
String TemperatureMeasurementStr = String.valueOf(measurement.getTemperature()) + "\u2103";
SpannableString tempSpan=  new SpannableString(TemperatureMeasurementStr);
if (TemperatureMeasurement.length() >0){
   
    //the symbol will be smaller then the number
    tempSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.7f),TemperatureMeasurementStr.length() - 1, TemperatureMeasurementStr.length(), 0);

    //the number style will be bold and the symbol normal
   tempSpan.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0,   TemperatureMeasurementStr.length()-1, 0);
  
    //the symbol color will be yellow
   tempSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), TemperatureMeasurementStr.length() - 1, TemperatureMeasurementStr.length(), 0);
 }
 temperatureTV.setText(tempSpan);
```

Finally, if you want just to type the degree symbol  "°" in any editor in windows (include android studio) just use:

```
                                    Alt+0176
```

or

```
                                    Alt+248
```

Answer (score 5):

There're a lot of ways to do it :

1.- You can create a `char` as follows :

```
char degreesymbol = '\u00B0';
```

Then you can add it on your `TextView`

2.- You can put it on your `XML` as follows :

```
android:text="50&#x2103;"
```

3.- And if you want to make it programmatically do it as follows :

```
YOURTEXTVIEW.setText((Your_Temperature) + " \u2109");
```

Answer (score 2):

`&#xb0;` is the HTML hex encoding for a [degree symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

'&#xb0' it's the unicode character for degree. Special characters are used in unicode format. (If you don't use the unicode character, usually shows up an alert)

Source:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

And if you want to know why you should use unicode characters, this website explains it:
'Unicode provides a unique number for every character(...) If your document calls for U+0289  it will be clear to any computer program what the character should be'
http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=UTConvertQ1

Answer (score 1):

`android:text="50&#xb0;` specifically `&#xb0;` is the HTML hex encoding!

Also,you can use `&#176;` it's the same thing.

For more http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

if you want to use code try this: `myTextView.setText ( "50" + (char) 0x00B0 );`

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="\u00B0"/>
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will help current and future users.

Answer (score 0):

The typographic symbol in the form of a superscript circle, which is usually denoted by the size of the values ​​of angles and temperatures, measured in [degrees celsius symbol](https://degreessymbolsign.com/degrees-sign-insert-degree-symbol-word-copy-and-paste/), is absent on the computer keyboard. However, in the encoding tables, the operating system uses to display characters on a computer screen. It is one of the first 128 characters in this table, which allows it to be used even in documents of the simplest text formats – for example, txt.

Comment: "is absent on the computer keyboard." - Not on mine - ° :) Whether or not this character is present on the keyboard or not depends on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**In XML, if you want to show android:text="32°" you can use:**

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
android:text="32&#xb0;"
android:id="@+id/myTV"></TextView>
```

**To do it programmatically, you can use:**

```
myTV.setText("32" + (char) 0x00B0);
```